# Get relative angle to collision Unity

Tags: unity, mathematics

I want to get the angle between the rotation (euler Angles) of the camera (V1 : `Vector3`) and the collision point of my character, when it hits a wall, to determin, if it was left, right, or in front of it.
I tried to use `Vector2.Angle` with V1 and V2 (`ControllerColliderHit.moveDirection` as a `Vector2`) to get the difference between them.

However I get a different value (0, 90, 180) when running into the wall depending on the world direction. (left wall, right wall, etc.)

How can I get the angle of the collision point relative to the direction the camera is facing?

[image]

Comment: What vector are you using to represent the camera's forward vector in `Vector2.Angle`?

Comment: It's orientation (transform.rotation)